# Active Admin create form in register_page

Tags: activeadmin, formtastic

Using ActiveAdmin (0.5.1) I would like to make multiple different forms for creating an object and saving it to my database. I'm trying to do this by using `ActiveAdmin.register_page`, but I'm running into trouble while trying to create the form. It seems that while using `register_page`, you do not get the same `form` method as in a `register` call. Here's the code:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "New Object" do
  content do
    para "Here you can create new objects!"
    para "This content will be replaced with links to the specialized forms"
  end
end
```

And the code for one of the forms:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Type 1" do
  menu :label => "Type 1", :parent => "New Object"

  content do
    panel "Attributes" do
      form do |f|
        f.input :color
        f.input :size
    end
  end
end
```

However this form will not render in any workable manner. Also `f.inputs` as well as many other methods you can see in examples (like [this](http://activeadmin.info/docs/5-forms.html)) do not work. Is it possible to make fully functional forms using `ActiveAdmin#register_page`?

Answer (score 3):

To create forms in a non-standard context (i.e., not a resource register), you need to use formtastic's `semantic_form_for` with the `:url` and `:builder` options specified.

```
content do
  semantic_form_for MyObject.new, :url => admin_my_objects_url, :builder => ActiveAdmin::FormBuilder do |f|
    f.inputs "My Object" do
      f.input :color
      f.input :size
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

This will give you a panel labeled "My Object" containing the form for your object with a submit button below it.

Comment: but if you give it an existing object. the fields won't be automatically filled with the object's attributes. and actually, I have not found a way to do it, yet.

Answer (score 3):

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Families Placement" do
  menu label: "Populaire Familles"

  page_action :update, method: :post do
    Family.find(params['id']).update_attributes(id_1: params['id_1'], id_2: params['id_2'])
    redirect_to "/"
  end

  content do
    Family.all.order(id: :asc).each do |family|
        form action: "families_placement/update", method: :post do |f|
            columns do
          panel family.name do
            f.input :id, type: :hidden, value:  family.id, name: 'id'
            f.input :id_1, as: :select, collection: collect_posts, value: family.id_1, name: 'id_1'
            f.input :id_2, as: :select, collection: collect_posts, value: family.id_2, name: 'id_2'
            f.input :authenticity_token, type: :hidden, name: :authenticity_token, value: form_authenticity_token
            f.input :submit, type: :submit
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You have an exemple of one working form in a custom ActiveAdmin page. Is very important to add

```
f.input :authenticity_token, type: :hidden, name: :authenticity_token, value: form_authenticity_token
```

This is where i found all informations to do this : https://asafdav2.github.io/2016/adding-forms-to-activeadmin-custom-pages/